# Jasper Report generating garbage data

Tags: jsf, pdf, jasper-reports

I have been using Jasper reports for a while and it worked with me great. but my colleague needed to change a model class and since then garbage data is generated instead of the expected PDF. the strange thing is the garbage data shows too even when i generate it from a different class, which hasnot been changed at all.

The output text is like this :

> %PDF-1.4 %���� 3 0 obj <>stream
>   x���m��:�����f����z��i��n��x����yΟ��\�h$;oo���xoL��4�����N�%��Xa���:�?B}�qYS._�ǟգ����p:�M�rc���^�~8�Z��Z�Ȫe��tٶ(=�~>R:&+JǪ�8�EK�x:��V�џ.UJ��tT��H՟����,TN�$5C�4�d5�r�sZs��5�a{u
>   �Z?�����bՆPu������Y]&ߘ�:.x�?�oulp�aR�# Q]�,#��3�/�+ gW�(�+
>   g7�)�+
>   g�.�W-�:f������u�\�ƽ�i��A;�v9^�ҫ���!�3���X�;�Ӟn�(zsl����JUS{��{��:�~�lD��Va�Q�QQL=j>���)�ܣ�NQ��G͇ثCkW����9-��PH�չ-jbh\¨�kit��uQ���Aek
>   V{�[,TY
>   �|��ޫCmG7��Y��Ѷ�q�2FY8ik>M�[`v0|�;�q*�Ӛ��Lp�L�j,�M3�;u���lukPG�U�Y�:)6T���x�����}�P7��

What should i do

Comment: What do you mean by "garbage data"?

Comment: like special characters and unorganized set of characters, it might be the binary representation of the PDF in a form of characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Seems that when I use Tomahawk servlet mapping tag in Web.xml file , it affects the jasper report PDF generation , those mapping tags are :

To use Tomahawk I have to add the following to "Web.xml" file:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 </filter-mapping>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

I do not know why this happened, but when I remove it , jasper report worked just fine